# How I can wait till a next task starts?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Program processes file, which is pretty small at first, finds some result and creates a new file to process. After a while the number of files increases rapidly.

I would like to process all files using QThreadPool. Can someone advise how I should make it or fix my idea?

I've decided to process each file in QThread and to send results and a new job with signals. Also, in the end of the `run()` function, it emits signal `taskDone` which is connected with slot `startNewTask` and it starts new QThread if there is some file to process and `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount()<MAX_THREAD_COUNT`. At the beginning I call a function `start` which calls `startNewTask` and waits for the completion of all threads (`QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();`). And here there is a problem: the signal `taskDone` was emitted but the function `start` has finished and the slot `startNewTask` has not been called.

How I should wait till the slot starts?